# Java regex match match whitespace and non-whitespace characters 2 times

Tags: java, regex

This is the pattern and string I am using for java regex matching. 
I need `'/dev/sda6         72342MB 5013MB  '` (i.e. whitespace non whitespce whitespace non whitespace)
in a single group.

```
String pattern = ".*\n(\\S+\\s+){2}(.*)";
String str = "Filesystem     1MB-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on\n" +
              "/dev/sda6         72342MB 5013MB   63655MB   8% /common";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern,  Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

But it is not coming as expected. 
It is matching

> 72342MB

instead of

> /dev/sda6         72342MB

Can anybody tell where am I going wrong ?

Comment: `String pattern = ".*\n(\\S+\\s+\\S+).*";` and don't forget to call `if (m.matches())` before you try to invoke `m.group(1)`

Comment: I'd also ask if the string you want match always starts with `/dev` (or at least always starts with `/`) and if the other two strings to match always end with `[Bb]`.

Comment: @markspace i need to match white space non whitespace chars 2 times 
just like abc 3 space def 3 space  .

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Are you sure?  I needs to match three things, not two. `"'/dev/sda6 72342MB 5013MB' in a single group"`

Comment: @markspace I get `/dev/sda6         72342MB` which is what OP said they wanted.

Comment: @markspace my bad i have edited the question. Using the {2} can't i group it ?
i know i can write something like (\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry I missed one thing. It shoud be another set of whitespace charcetes after 72342MB. How can I accomplish this using {2} notation ? i know adding another //s will do the task.
something like
(\\S+\\s+){2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

- You need to always call, `matches()` or `find()` before invoking `.group()` methods on matcher object.
- Second your regex is incorrectly grouped.

Currently your group will only give one/last match, so instead you need to wrap whole of your expression into group. The correct regex you need is this,

```
.*\n((?:\\S+\\s+){2})(.*)
```

Try this Java codes,

```
String pattern = ".*\n((?:\\S+\\s+){2})(.*)";
String str = "Filesystem     1MB-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on\n" +
              "/dev/sda6         72342MB 5013MB   63655MB   8% /common";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern,  Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Prints,

```
/dev/sda6         72342MB
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know ?: will not remember the recently captured group. and yeah i needed to capture the whole thing. Thanks.

Comment: `?:` is used to make a group non-grouping pattern, as by default a parenthesis always creates a grouping pattern. The above regex would still have worked without even `?:` in the regex but it is a good practice to turn any grouping pattern into non-grouping pattern, if you don't need them.